# How to click on calendar icon using class in angular protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

HTML code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

In protractor angular automation, I am trying to click on calendar icon using class but am not able to click. Using `ng-click` I can click on the icon but I have to do using class. Please help me, I am new to angular protractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the classes this button has a "layout-oriented" and it's not a good idea to rely on them. But, if you insist:

```
element(by.css("button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm.pull-right"));
```

Probably, the most reliable and readable locator in this case (given what is given) is `ng-click`:

```
element(by.css("button[ng-click*=move]"));
```

Comment: Hi alecxe, thanks for that example, in my case i tried `element(by.css("button[ng-click*=createWL]"));` but it did'nt click into it !  Here the html code : ` <button class="md-icon-button watchlist-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" id="addWL" aria-label="Add Watchlist" ng-click="createWL()"> <ng-md-icon icon="add_circle_outline" class="ng-scope"> `

Comment: @Emna hey, what do you mean by "didn't click into it" exactly? Do you have a question about the problem already created? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i have created a question yesterday about it. My problem is that the test is passed and no action is executed (i have tried the options you have suggested to me before) i 'm not sure because it's an icon button if i'm locating it correctly!