# Click into an icon isn't working on protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

I have an icon to add a new item, i want to click into it but the action isn't done. I don't know if i'm locating the element in a right way ?

I have tried the answer provided in that [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586911/how-to-click-on-calendar-icon-using-class-in-angular-protractor) :

```
element(by.css('[ng-click="createWL()"]')).click();

element(by.css("button[ng-click*=createWL]")).click();
```

But it didn't work for me.

Here my html code : `<button class="md-icon-button watchlist-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" id="addWL" aria-label="Add Watchlist" ng-click="createWL()"> <ng-md-icon icon="add_circle_outline" class="ng-scope">`

Comment: Did you try 'element(by.css(".watchlist-icon-button")).click();'?

Comment: i have just tried it, it tells me that more than one element found, i'll try to make an all selection than find which onei need ;)

Comment: It looks that there are 3 elements, I have tried with all of them get(0) , then get(1) and get(2) but the test is passed and no action is done !

Comment: Have you tried the options provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36940011/771848)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes yes ;) first thing i done. But i have a doubt am i locating it right?

Comment: have you tried to use the id? element(by.css('#addWL')).click();

Comment: @lauda : i have already solve it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that this test is executed before it's time so that it's failed and we didn't even see that icon in the screen.

So fix it with some wait ;) and test priority.